# Strange behavior involving right-click on laptop

Tags: laptop, autohotkey, synaptics-touchpad

(Synaptics TouchPad V1.3 on SMB Port, 19.0.19.1 / Windows 10, all updates installed)

Left-click is working normally on my laptop. However, when I click the right-click button, nothing happens.

The strange part: Sometimes my primary key will be reversed. In other words, sometimes when I click the left-click button, the right-click is triggered (context menu shows up, etc.) But when I go into my mouse settings, it will say the primary key is currently set to Left, and if I change it to Right, it goes back to normal (i.e. physical left-click button = left-click trigger, even though the primary key setting says Right now).

I just installed AutoHotkey to remap my right Alt key to my right-click button (`RAlt::RButton`) in the meantime and sometimes it ignores my current primary key setting. For instance, when I have my primary key set to Right in my settings, `RAlt::RButton` will trigger left click and **so will the physical left-click button**.

It doesn't make sense. What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

One potential thing you could look at would be to see if you can pull the physical right mouse button off and clean things out.  Sometimes that will fix it if it's a hardware issue (and sometimes it won't do anything).

It also sounds like the weirdness you have with the mouse operation being opposite of the primary button set only happens when you're messing with the settings--does it do that if you restart the computer and don't change the settings?  i.e., does the mouse go from working to not working without any settings change, but then adjusting the settings will fix it?

Regarding the AutoHotkey script, in the AutoHotkey help documentation for `Click` it has this note:

> NOTE: Unlike MouseClick, the left and right buttons behave
>   consistently across all systems, even if the user has swapped the
>   buttons via the system's control panel.

So `Click` and `MouseClick` work differently and it's possible the `RAlt::RButton` reassignment falls into the category where it takes the OS button assignment into account.  One thing you could do would be to try the two different commands below in place of the straight key reassignment and see if one of them has the results you're after...

```
RAlt::Click Right
```

or

```
RAlt::MouseClick Right
```